File Read Write and Storage Permissions For All Api (Android)
I want check Storage Permission (as well as File Read/write Premissions) for All Api. I am something confused. Because in old Api, there is called android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but in new api for scoped storage this permissions not needed. Now the storage permissions are
       Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
       Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO,
       Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO

But, My app will run in all api's. So I want a "One Method"- that could check all necessary file/Storage permissions correspending to all Api (to 34). I am Trying the following, but it seems some ANR in play console stack Trace, I cant figure Out if any problem in my codes, I think, is the below method is enough to check storage permissions (including Notification Permissions) for all api ? Any help is appreciated, Thanks in Advance :
public static boolean checkFilePermissions(Context mContext) {


        int permissionReadExternalStorage;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
            permissionReadExternalStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES);
        else
            permissionReadExternalStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


        int permissionWriteExtarnalStorage;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
            permissionWriteExtarnalStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO);
        else
            permissionWriteExtarnalStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (permissionWriteExtarnalStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO);
            else
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        }

        if (permissionReadExternalStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES);
            else
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {

            int permissionVideoStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO);
            if (permissionVideoStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO);

            }

            int notificationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                    Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);

            if (notificationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);

            }

        }
        return listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty();
    }

